# Checking if string contains a set of chars not working batch

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to make a program that detects if the string that is entered contains +, -, *, or / and then evaluates it. The problem is that var is always defined whether the string contains the characters or not.

## **Examples:**

Input: not a math command

Output: var is defined (math input

What I wanted: var is not defined

Input:10+10

Output: var is defined (math input

What I wanted: var is defined (math input

Input: ABC123

Output: var is defined (math input

What I wanted: var is not defined

I have adapted my code from this link:

[how to check if a parameter (or variable) is numeric in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584282/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-or-variable-is-numeric-in-windows-batch-file)

## **Code:**

```
@echo off

SET "var="

set /p "COMMAND=Enter command>"

for /f "delims=^+-^*/" %%i in ("%COMMAND%") do set "var=%%i"


if not defined var (
    echo var not defined
) else (
    echo var is defined (math input)
)

pause
```

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you are entering and what you are expecting from that entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - the code you are using is designed to detect whether the string in question contains **only** numerics or not.

Your requirement appears to be to detect whether the string contains at least one of the delimiters.

for /f "tokens=1*delims=^+-^*/" %%i in ("%COMMAND%") do set "svar=%%i"&set "var=%%j"

will set `svar` to the part before and `var` to the part after a delimiter  **but** it will ignore any leading delimiter characters and will not object to successive delimiters such as `abc++//++def` as the partitioning into `tokens` observes the subject string as a sequence `delimstoken1delimstoken2...`

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you were doing with the svar but what does the tokens=1* part mean?

Comment: The string is `command` is interpreted as a sequence of tokens and delimiter-sequences. "tokens=1*" means select the 1st token to `%%i`, and that remaining after the delimiter found to `%%j` (next `metavariable` in alphabetical sequence). The `tokens` selected may be separated by `,` or a range separated by `-` so "tokens=1,2,4-7,9*" selects the 1st token to `%%i`, 2nd to `%%j`, 4th .. 7th to `%%k..%%n`, 9th to `%%o` and `%%p` gets the remainder of the string from the beginning of the 10th token (the one after the highest explicitly chosen) - see `for /?|more` from the prompt for docco

Answer (score 0):

To ensure there are only digits and arithmetic operators in `%command%` there are several ways,
I'd use `findstr.exe` limited regular expression features.

As spaces in `%command%` will disturb the result I remove them
(the minus has to be escaped with a backslash because it denotes a range in a [class]):

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\07\21\SO_45225802.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Cls
:loop
SET "var="
set /p "ArithmeticExpression=Enter arithmetic expression> "

:: Check if input consists of only numbers and operators
Echo:%ArithmeticExpression: =%|Findstr "^[0-9+\-*/][0-9+\-*/]*$" >NUL 2>&1
If Errorlevel 1 (
    Echo Invalid characters in %ArithmeticExpression%
) Else (
    Set /a "var=%ArithmeticExpression%"
    If defined var (
      Echo %ArithmeticExpression% evaluates to !var!
    ) Else (
      Echo Error evaluating %ArithmeticExpression%
    ) 
)
Goto :loop
```

Sample run:

```
Enter arithmetic expression> 1 + 1
1 + 1 evaluates to 2
Enter arithmetic expression> 10 * 3
10 * 3 evaluates to 30
Enter arithmetic expression> 30 -3
30 -3 evaluates to 27
Enter arithmetic expression> 27 / 3
27 / 3 evaluates to 9
Enter arithmetic expression> ABC123
Invalid characters in ABC123
Enter arithmetic expression> 10/0
Divide by zero error.
Error evaluating 10/0
Enter arithmetic expression>
```