# IF "71" GTR "7000" yields true

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

According to my code, If `%~1` is greater than `7000`, go to `ExceedError`

```
IF "%~1" GTR "7000" GOTO ExceedError
```

Contents of `ExceedError`:

```
ECHO Value exceeded the maximum value. See help file.
EXIT /B
```

But this happened:

```
...modules>If "71" GTR "7000" GOTO ExceedError

...modules>Echo Value exceeded the maximum value. See help file.
Value exceeded the maximum value. See help file.

...modules>exit /B
```

What happened? Is there something wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I thought it could add more further details of what happened to the problem, so I added those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you've enclosed arguments with double quotes and this forces a string comparison.
To compare numbers try without the quotes:

`IF %~1 GTR 7000 GOTO ExceedError`

In case you want to prevent errors you can add one more line:

```
set /a "_number=%~1" >nul 2>&1 || set "_number=0"
IF %_number% GTR 7000 GOTO ExceedError
```

In case of wrong input you'll compare the values with a `0` as default value. You can change it if you need

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Thank you for solving the problem! But what if they typed symbols on `%~1`, for example `>EE#`. It contains the illegal character `>`. So the script would interpret it wrong, and do something different. My goal is "unless it's a number, `GOTO ExceedError`". Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @scriptmastere02 That’s a separate question. Please check [how to check if a parameter (or variable) is numeric in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17584282/711006), for example.

Comment: @Melebius It won't change the problem of accepting illegal characters.

Comment: This method to test for valid numbers is not reliable. There are a ton of inputs that will not cause an error, like `!-~123` or the _name_ of any variable, like `AA123`. If the variable is not defined or contains an invalid number, the result is zero with no error. If the variable contains a valid number the result is such a number; this could lead to strange errors...