# Check if user input meets the requirements and parse its content

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that prompts a user to enter a number sequence that is 6 numbers long. I also want to check if that input includes, for example, three of the number `5` within it.

```
@echo off
set /p UserInput=
if %UserInput% has........(
goto Number_Has_Three_5
)else(
goto Number_Dosent_Have_Three_5
)
```

This would check if the input has only numbers and then if it has three of the number five in it.

For example, the number `111155` is six numbers long but doesn't have three fives so it wouldn't work and it would goto the error message.

But the number `111555`, since it has three of the number five in it instead of two fives, would work and the script would continue.

Comment: exactly three fives or at least three fives?

Comment: all fives in a row (`111555`) or not (`152535`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of doing 4 different tasks:

- Is `UserInput` not null
- [Is `UserInput` numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584282/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-or-variable-is-numeric-in-windows-batch-file)
- Is `UserInput` 6 digits
- Does `UserInput` contain three 5s

There are two ambiguities to your question however:
***Do the three 5s need to be together (`152535 = false`, `123555 = true`)?

Can there be more than three 5s (`125555 = false`, `555123 = true`)?***

My code allows for the 5s to be anywhere in the 6 character string, and will output true if there are <s>at least</s> **exactly** three of them.

```
:: ...
if not defined UserInput (
    echo False. No Input.
    goto:eof
)

set "testVar="
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%UserInput%") do set testVar=%%i
if defined testVar (
    echo False. Not Numeric.
    goto:eof
)

set testVar=%UserInput%000000
if not %testVar:~0,6%==%UserInput% (
    echo False. Not 6 digits.
    goto:eof
)

set testVar=%UserInput:5=%
if not defined testVar goto:true
if not %testVar:~3,1%#==# (
    echo False. Less than three 5s.
    goto:eof
)
:: Edit: More than three 5s result in false
if %testVar:~2,1%#==# (
    echo False. More than three 5s.
    goto:eof
)

:true
echo True.
:: ...
```

Comment: Very good code! I want to suggest one more `if` condition block below the first one with first line being `set "UserInput=%UserImput:"=%"` to remove all by mistake entered double quotes. Then once again `if not defined UserInput (` is used to make sure environment variable `UserInput` is still defined at all after removing all `"`. The reason is that on German keyboard pressing by mistake __Shift+2__ instead of just __2__ results in typing `"` instead of `2`. A user input string with one or more `"` can break execution of batch file because of a syntax error.

Comment: @Mofi Great suggestion. Would definitely recommend anyone relying on user input sterilise the resulting string. I think it's a bit out of scope for my answer as it wasn't in the original question. There's also a lot more that could break the script than just a `"`, and I don't want to account for them all.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
:loop 
set /p "userinput=Input: "
echo %userinput%|findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" >nul || (
    echo invalid input
    goto :loop
)
set "nofives=%userinput:5=%0123456"
set /a fives=%nofives:~6,1%
echo %userinput% has %fives% fives.
if %fives% == 3 goto :three
goto :loop
:three
echo insert your payload here
```

`findstr` checks, if the input consists of exactly 6 numbers.

`set nofives...` removes any `5` and adds a counter string

`%nofives:~6,1%` gets the seventh character (counting is zero-based!) which is the count of fives.

As this effectively *counts* the number of fives (expandable to an input of max nine numbers **1)**), you are free to handle "exactly three" (`if %fives% == 3`) or "minimum three" (`if %fives% geq 3`) or whatever you want.

To show how it works, let's assume `%userinput%` is `abcdef` (just to not confuse it with the counter string) 
If we remove nothing from `%userinput%` and add the counter string, it looks like:

```
abcdef0123456
      ^ this char is the count (seventh char)
```

If we remove one char (abcdef -> abcdf) and add the counter string, it looks like:

```
abcdf0123456
      ^ this char is the count (seventh char)
```

and so on until "remove six chars (for you that would be an user input of `555555`). then it looks like:

```
0123456
      ^ this char is the count (seventh char)
```

**1)** with two slight changes expandable up to 15 numbers (using a hexadecimal counter string):

```
set "nofives=%userinput:5=%0123456789ABCDEF"
set /a fives=0x%nofives:~6,1%
```