# Check OS version and variable for Network Label

Tags: variables, batch-file, set, environment, netsh

I've been using this code successfully however, looking to adjust it and use when performing netsh commands to rename NIC's - although whilst writing this i'm not sure it's the best route anymore.

```
SET _OSVer=OTHER
FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%a IN ('VER') DO SET _VerNo=%%a
FOR /F "Tokens=2-3 Delims=. " %%b IN ("%_VerNo%") DO (
    IF "%%b.%%c" EQU "5.2" SET _OSVer=2003
    IF "%%b.%%c" EQU "6.0" SET _OSVer=2008
    IF "%%b.%%c" EQU "6.1" SET _OSVer=2008R2
    IF "%%b.%%c" EQU "6.2" SET _OSVer=2012
    IF "%%b.%%c" EQU "6.3" SET _OSVer=2012R2
)

IF "%_OSVer%" EQU "2003" (ECHO %_OSVer% )
IF "%_OSVer%" EQU "2008" (ECHO %_OSVer% )
IF "%_OSVer%" EQU "2008R2" (ECHO %_OSVer% )
IF "%_OSVer%" EQU "20012" (ECHO %_OSVer% )
IF "%_OSVer%" EQU "20012R2" (ECHO %_OSVer% )
```

FYI: Pre2012 network labels are Local Area Connection, 2012 is Ethernet.

I want to execute the following command

```
netsh interface set interface name = "%NETWORKNAME%" newname = "network-storage"  >nul 2>&1
```

I'm thinking based on the OSversion %NETWORKNAME% would be defined as either "Local Area Connection" or "Ethernet"

Can I use something like

```
  IF "%_OSVer%" EQU "2003" + "2008" + "2008R2" SET Networkname="Local Area Network"
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT - From Pauls Feeback, final code is**

```
 SET NICNaming=OTHER
FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%a IN ('VER') DO SET _VerNo=%%a
FOR /F "Tokens=2-3 Delims=. " %%b IN ("%_VerNo%") DO (
    IF "%%b.%%c" LEQ  "6.1" SET NICNaming=Local Area Connection
    IF "%%b.%%c" GEQ  "6.2" SET NICNaming=Ethernet

)

ECHO %NICNaming%

netsh interface set interface name = "%NICNaming%" newname = "network-storage"  >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel%== 0 (Echo found) ELSE (Echo missing abort)
```

Thanks
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13212116) are a valuable answer for such thing.

If I had to adapt, it would be like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
GOTO CHKVERS

:action
rem action
SET "Networkname=Local Area Network"
GOTO:EOF


:CHKVERS
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
if "%version%" == "6.3" goto action &REM Windows 8.1
if "%version%" == "6.2" goto action &REM Windows 8.
if "%version%" == "6.1" goto action &REM Windows 7.
if "%version%" == "6.0" goto action &REM Windows Vista.

echo Version undetermined, please contact an administrator.

endlocal
exit /b 0
```

You may also like:

```
IF "%A%"=="1" IF "%B%"=="1" IF "%C%"=="1" GOTO YES
GOTO NO
```

You may use GEQ and LEQ

```
IF "%version%" GEQ "6.0" IF "%version%" LEQ "6.3" GOTO YES
GOTO NO
```

> EQU : Equal
>
> NEQ : Not equal
>
> LSS : Less than <
>
> LEQ : Less than or Equal <=
>
> GTR : Greater than >
>
> GEQ : Greater than or equal >=
>
> This 3 digit syntax is necessary because the > and < symbols are recognised as redirection operators

http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: Paul, so obvious now! - thank you don't know why i didn't even think LEQ or GEQ! - with a couple simple (very) adjustments i've achieved what i wanted with your help, thanks Paul!