# get-CimInstance for powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What is the equivalent of Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem for powershell 2.0? Or maybe the equivalence to get relent data to know if a computer is running Windows 7 or 8. Right now I use get-ciminstance to the version. 6.2 is windows 8 and 6.1 is windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Get-WmiObject**. If you're trying to get the OS version number:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Version
```

Comment: But isn't that cmdlet only [available](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824(v=wps.620).aspx) in PowerShell 3+?

Comment: No, it's been [available since PowerShell 1.0](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/powershell/powershell10/get-wmiobject/). It's just that PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0 docs have apparently been removed from TechNet.

Answer (score 3):

You can also determine the OS version without resorting to WMI [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330368/1630171):

```
[System.Environment]::OSVersion
```