# How to get the correct Windows version from command line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, version

How to get the correct Windows version from command line, PowerShell included?

As I've tried all solutions/answers from [How to find the Windows version from the PowerShell command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330187/how-to-find-the-windows-version-from-the-powershell-command-line), but none is able to give this now:

[image]

Comment: It's in the registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve it from the registry:

```
# -> e.g. '22H2'
Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' DisplayVersion
```

Note:

- Apparently only works in version `20H2` and above.
- Prior to that, `winver.exe` (whose screenshot is shown in the question), apparently showed the `ReleaseId` registry value (in lieu of `DisplayVersion` above).
- As for **terminology**: I'm not sure if there's an official name for this information, but, given the name of the registry value, ***display version*** sounds reasonable.

Comment: A simple follow up question -- what's the PS's syntax to put it in a string? In normal *nix shell, I'd use `"Windows version \'that command\'"`

Comment: @xpt `"Windows version $(...)"`, using an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).